# Does rem refer to the users preset size before its set in html tag?

Tags: css, responsive-design, accessibility

Let's say that end user has issues reading smaller text, so they've set their browser to default to 20px. If I set the rem size like this:

```
    html {
      font-size: max(1rem, 2.5vh);
    }
```

Will it override their preference, or would it set "rem" to their preference (20px, in this case)? I don't want to break accessibility, but also want to scale the font with the screen-size. It seems to work on my end, but I want to be sure this is the best method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"rem" refers to computed value of font-size of the root element, so the result of the `font-size: max(1rem, 2.5vh);` setting.

1rem applied to the font-size of the root element = 1em, so the rem size is the result of `max(20px, 2.5vh)` if the user has set the default to 20px.

To cite [MDN on the `<length>` unit rem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#rem)

> rem
>
> Represents the font-size of the root element (typically `<html>`). When used within the root element font-size, it represents its initial value (a common browser default is 16px, but user-defined preferences may modify this).

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was trying to accomplish, I just wanted to be sure that the code pulled rem from the end user if I hadn't defined it yet.